# Coldfusion Layout Page

Tags: layout, coldfusion

Is it possible to create layouts with ColdFusion? I want to automatically include footer and header sections on any page I add to the project, without using cfinclude.
because this is not true.

''''
Can I do this using application.cfc?

Do you have any information?

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel use [ColdBox](https://www.coldbox.org/)

Comment: *because this is not true.*: because *what* is not true?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `onRequestStart()` and `onRequestEnd()` to add a header and footer to every page throughout the application, but you don't want to do that. And how do you add those files to those parts of the request? By using `<cfinclude>` inside those functions.

The first problem is that not every request will be a returning HTML; some might only return data. Depending on your application's complexity, there will be several other problems with this approach. As @Miguel-F suggests, use a framework with a simple-to-implement layout feature like ColdBox.

https://coldbox.ortusbooks.com/the-basics/layouts-and-views/layouts

```
<cfoutput>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>#prc.title#</title>
</head>
<body>
  <!--- Header: Direct Render --->
  #renderView( view='tags/header')#

  <div id="content">
    <!--- Render set view --->
    #renderView()#
  </div>

  #renderView( view='tags/footer' )#
</body>
</html>
</cfoutput>
```

But again, the surprise is that under the hood, it's still using `<cfinclude>` everywhere because that function's purpose is to reuse CFM code across an application.